# Align a GtkLabel relative to a GtkDrawingArea

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtk2

I have a GtkLabel and a GtkDrawingArea within a VBox, I want to center the label relative to a X-coordinate of the GtkDrawingArea (which is below of the label in the VBox), how can I tell GTK to center that label relative to that "anchor" point ? This point should be the center of the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `gtk_alignment_new` in order to create a centered alignment and then I used `gtk_alignment_set_padding` to fill the right padding with the amount of padding needed to align with an arbitrary x-axis value. Thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 2):

Since your GtkLabel and GtlDrawingArea are inside a GtkVBox, then their position are relative to each other. The following should set the alignment of the label to the center:

```
gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(label), 0.5F /*X*/, 0.5F /*Y*/);
```

---

If you don't want to center the text of the GtkLabel, then you might use GtkAlignment widget:

```
GtkWidget* helper;

helper = gtk_alignment_new(0.5F /*X*/, 0.5F /*Y*/, 0.0F, 0.0F);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(helper), label);

gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(vbox), helper);
```

You can realign it again by calling `gtk_alignment_set` function.

Comment: See the part where I say "I want to center the label relative to a X-coordinate of the GtkDrawingArea", I don't want the label to be centered with the GtkDrawingArea and yes centered against an arbitrary x-axis point of the GtkDrawingArea.

Comment: @Tarantula: I edited my answer, now it maybe is the answer, otherwise it's my fault that i can't understand your mean.

Comment: Thanks for answering PC2st, I solved it using the gtk_alignment_set_padding, look the answer.